# Does the class of unbiased estimators of a parameter form some algebraic structure?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

For example if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are unbiased estimators of $\theta$, so is $\frac{U_1+U_2}{2}$

Does this class of unbiased estimators of a parameter form some well studied algebraic structure?

Comment: Any convex combination $cU_1+(1-c)U_2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ where $c\in [0,1]$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am not sure you need to restrict $c$ to $[0,1]$

Comment: @Henry Oops! Yes, any $c$ will do.